# Можно ли как-то связать гугл таблицы с какой-то црм или бд для колл центра?

Tags: mysql, google-spreadsheet, crm

Наверняка я не первый, кто задается этим вопросом, если у кого-то есть подобный опыт, поделитесь, пожалуйста. Если кратко, нужно как-то связать гугл таблицы, либо с какой-то црм для колл-центра, либо какой-то базой данных, чтобы была интеграция между ними. Грубо говоря, звонит какой-то человек, я внес его в бд для звонков и по кнопке у меня информация об этом всем "улетела" в гугл таблицы. Хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли это технически и может быть есть какие-то примеры "живого" использования.
Спасибо заранее за ответы.

Comment: Конечно возможно, у Гугл-Таблиц есть АПИ, и Вы можете написать код с вообще любой логикой связи этих таблиц со своей БД или ЦРМ. Например, можно запускать регулярно скрипт на сервере, который будет вытягивать новые записи из БД в таблицы. По ЦРМ смотрите API/SDK конкретной CRM, что и как можно сделать там, скорее всего там будет дёргаться callback-url на Вашем сервере с инфой по новостям.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если на GAS то вот ссылка https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc
В интернете достаточно видео по которым можно сделать.